# Custom post type pagination like "previous current/all next"

Tags: pagination

I have custom post type `works` with custom taxonomy `work_category`
I want to build such pagination while viewing `single.php`

**previous 2/25 next**

[`link to previous post in custom tax`] [`current post number`]/[`all post number from custom tax`] [`next post in custom tax`]

Currently i can't get `current post number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it

For previous/next use [Ambrosite Next/Previous Post Link Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ambrosite-nextprevious-post-link-plus/)

To get current/all use following code inside the loop

```
        $query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'works',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => '-1',
            'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'work_category',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => 'design'
                    )
            ),
            'order' => 'ASC'
        ) );
        $all = $query->post_count;
        foreach( $query->posts as $key => $p )
            if( $post->ID == $p->ID ) $current = $key + 1;

        echo $current.'/'.$all;
```